# SQLite: PreLoadSQLite_BaseDirectory ignored?

Tags: sqlite, sqlite-net

The documentation [here](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact?ci=trunk&filename=Doc/Extra/Provider/environment.html) indicates that I should be able to use a PreLoadSQLite_BaseDirectory environment variable in order to load the sqlite native libraries (x86\SQLite.Interop.dll and x64\SQLite.Interop.dll) from a different location other than that of the executing assembly.

However this seems to be completely ignored.

I am running an ASP.NET application using IIS Express.  The workaround is to copy the x64 and x86 directories to C:\program files (x86)\IIS Express.  This works fine and my application can then run, but I don't want to have to do this.

Anyone run into this issue?

The packages I have installed are:

```
SQLite.Net Extensions-PCL v1.3.0
SQLite.Net PCL - Win32 Platform v2.5.1
SQLite.net PCL v3.0.5
System.Data.SQLite Core (x86/x64) v1.0.96.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the most recent version of the Win32 platform resolver for SqLite PCL has a [new parameter](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/blob/a34a7a8fcbc2f78e85c630c4e71e8e138a9dd2fa/src/SQLite.Net.Platform.Win32/SQLitePlatformWin32.cs) in the constructor that allows one to specify a native library search path.  So I am just using this instead of trying to figure out why the aforementioned environment variables (also in config file form) are completely ignored.